# Silverlight Partially overlay two controls

Tags: silverlight

I have a `Border` and a `ToggleButton` inside it. Except, I want the togglebutton's position to be half outside the border and half inside it and over it. How can I do this?

Comment: It would help if you included the Xaml as it stands now

Comment: Its not much. just a <border> and a <ToggleButton> inside it

Comment: It may not seem that complex but whether the border is stretched by a containing Grid will have an impact on the answer as will whether you have give the toggle button a specific width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are various answers depending on other circumstances. In the current absence of some sample Xaml, lets assume for the moment you want the toggle button to shifted to the left out of the border, that you known the exact width of the button and the Border is wrapped tightly round the button. (Thats a lot of assumption).

You can shift something out of a border by using a negative margin.  For example if the ToggleButton has the width of 100 then the margin "-50 0 50 0" would shift it to the left by half.